# "find" command does not find

Tags: linux, find

I know I have the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
I wanted to find it because I didn't remember the path.

Referring to this, https://linux.die.net/man/1/find , and some comments of people with the same problem using "find" I tried:
`find / sshd_config` and `sudo find / sshd_config` and `find /etc sshd_config`  and `find /etc/ssh sshd_config`

Result: No such file or directory

[image]

I'd like to know why `find` does not find that file.  I also like to know if it is not the right command, which command is the right one ti find a file when we don't know the path (also using wildcard will help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an expression. A simple one, case-insensitive name: `find /etc -iname sshd_config`. The man page shows you all the other expressions you can use.

Comment: I though ``-iname`` was a parameter for _case insensitive name_ and just the name was enough as expression. Thanks. (I found it needs ``sudo`` too)

Comment: Noop, you need -name or -iname to search for a name. Also, You don't need to be root (sudo) to find /etc/ssh/sshd_config since /etc, /etc/ssh as well as /etc/ssh/sshd_config have the read permission set for 'other'. You'll just get a lot of error messages about directories your not allowed to read and therefore should redirect stderr to /dev/null. (e.g. `find / -name sshd_config 2>/dev/null`)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `-name` parameter

`find /etc/ssh -name sshd_config` should work just fine